# AngularJs Select Generated Through PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I have created a simple PHP function for my AngularJS application. I want to select default option and it should be visible. Unfortunately, It's not selecting my desired value.

My Function is as follows:

```php
function qtyList($selectName, $selectQty){
    $str = '<select ng-model="qty" ng-change="updateCart('.$selectName.',qty)">';

    for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++){
        if($selectQty == $i)
            $str .= '<option ng-selected="selected">'.$i.'</option>';
        else
            $str .= '<option>'.$i.'</option>';
    }

    $str .= '</select>';

    return $str;
}
```

Please help with any suggestion.

Comment: @Mosh Feu, Thanks for formatting.

Comment: My pleasure :) By the way, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/303669) the answer so it will help to other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the angular model (qty) also has the correct value.

```
<?php


function qtyList($selectName, $selectQty)
{

    $str = '<select ng-init="qty =\'' . $selectQty . '\'" ng-model="qty">';

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
        $str .= '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
    }

    $str .= '</select>';

    return $str;
}


echo qtyList('testName', "5");
```

Comment: Excellent, That is exactly I need.